# R define columns for a function

Tags: r, function

What I am trying to do is to take levels of factors in one column and from these levels create additional columns, after that, I have trouble to write a function that would return 1 or 0 to a column with the same name as the one level of a factor in the first column. The goal is to have at the end a lot of columns of factors with 1 or 0 if the factor (have the same name as the column) is present in the row of the first column.

```
    levels <- levels(zivnosti$X41)
    zivnosti[ ,dput(as.character(levels))] <- NA
    
    IF2 <- function(x){
      
      if (x %in% dput(as.character(levels(zivnosti$X41))) & x == zivnosti[[col_name]]  ){
        return(1)
      } 
      else {
        return(0)
      }
    }
    
    zivnosti[ ,dput(as.character(levels))] <- sapply(zivnosti$X41,IF2)
```

I would like to do the same thing with the third column as I did for the second

[image]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Are you looking or `class.ind`?

Comment: Not really, I add a picture of what I am searching for. I would like to have a function that would give 1 or 0 in a column with the same name as one of the factors in the first column according to its occurrence. It is quite difficult to explain, just have a look at the picture. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but maybe you can use [`pivot_wider()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) from `tidyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# example dataset
zivnosti <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
  X1     X2         X3
   1    VZP     obchod
   2    VZP  ubytovani
   3    VZP  pristroje
")

# create wide dataset
zivnosti %>%
  mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("X1", "X2"), names_from = X3, values_from = dummy, values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      X1 X2    obchod ubytovani pristroje
#>   <int> <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 VZP        1         0         0
#> 2     2 VZP        0         1         0
#> 3     3 VZP        0         0         1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that:

- you need to create some dummy variable (`mutate(dummy = 1)`) to get "positive value" (then you see `values_from = dummy`),
- you need to define columns that will remain untouched (`id_cols = c("X1", "X2")`),
- you need to create some dummy variable to get "positive value" (then you see `values_from = dummy`) and for zeros you define a fallback value (`values_fill = 0`).

#### Function?

If you want a simple fnction that will keep the original columns while creating the new ones with `0` or `1`, I have tried this (although not very clean and probably not very effective `base R` solution):

```
# dummy data frame
zivnosti <- data.frame(
  X1 = sample(2983:2992),
  X40 = "Vseobecna_pece",
  X41 = sample(c("obchod", "ubytovani", "pristroje"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

print(zivnosti)
#>      X1            X40       X41
#> 1  2983 Vseobecna_pece ubytovani
#> 2  2990 Vseobecna_pece pristroje
#> 3  2992 Vseobecna_pece pristroje
#> 4  2985 Vseobecna_pece pristroje
#> 5  2991 Vseobecna_pece pristroje
#> 6  2988 Vseobecna_pece ubytovani
#> 7  2989 Vseobecna_pece    obchod
#> 8  2986 Vseobecna_pece ubytovani
#> 9  2987 Vseobecna_pece    obchod
#> 10 2984 Vseobecna_pece    obchod

# this is some kind of transforming function...
change <- function(df, column) {
  # 1 for correct column
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df[i, df[i, column]] <- 1
  }
  # replace NAs with 0
  df[is.na(df)] <- 0
  # return the changed data frame
  return(df)
}

# try that on our dummy data frame
change(zivnosti, "X41")
#>      X1            X40       X41 ubytovani pristroje obchod
#> 1  2983 Vseobecna_pece ubytovani         1         0      0
#> 2  2990 Vseobecna_pece pristroje         0         1      0
#> 3  2992 Vseobecna_pece pristroje         0         1      0
#> 4  2985 Vseobecna_pece pristroje         0         1      0
#> 5  2991 Vseobecna_pece pristroje         0         1      0
#> 6  2988 Vseobecna_pece ubytovani         1         0      0
#> 7  2989 Vseobecna_pece    obchod         0         0      1
#> 8  2986 Vseobecna_pece ubytovani         1         0      0
#> 9  2987 Vseobecna_pece    obchod         0         0      1
#> 10 2984 Vseobecna_pece    obchod         0         0      1
```

(Note that it works with small dataset without any other `NA`s, however, I'll try to find something better if you'll think it's the right way.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it was very helpful :) however, it does not solve my problem entirely... I mean you understood it very well nevertheless the problem is that am searching for a possibility of how to define my columns in order to create a function that I can use: IF a factor (string) in a row bears the same name as a column return 1 in the column of the name in the row where the factor is. Sorry for my difficult explanation. (asi už to nedávám :D Každopádně Děkuji za odpověď, v Česku pravděpodobně není moc lidí co by dělalo s R)

Comment: @JaroslavKotrba Hello, sooo, if I understand it, you want to keep the original columns and only create a function that will help you to fill the new columns with 0 and 1? I have tried to update the answer with a new section - there is a new `change()` function (probably not very effective on large datasets), where you provide a data frame and a column name to pick the column names. Try that, please, and let me know. Otherwise I'll probably provide a [contact](https://www.root.cz/autori/petr-kajzar/) to be able to explain in Czech :-)

Comment: Thank you very much :))) This is what I was searching for. However, it is most likely not suitable for large datasets with NAs, as you mentioned but It worked so far fine for my dataset. I just cannot believe that it works :D I have to check it once more tomorrow morning :D really you made my day!!!. Your effort to help is fantastic, I wish I had had such teachers at school. I mean I spent hours trying to find a solution before I posted my problem here. May I just keep your contact in order to stay in touch? as I really fell for R :)

Comment: @JaroslavKotrba Wow, great, thanks for your feedback, I'm really great it works for you! And of course, feel free to contact me. :-)